# Create a 1's and 0's Matrix in MATLAB where the amount of 1's has a limit

Tags: matlab, random, matrix

If for example I had:

```
A = 5
B = randi([0 1], 5, 5)
```

I would be making a 5x5 matrix of random one's and zeros'

How could I limit the matrix so it only had the amount of 1's as the value of `A`, so 5 1's in this case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here a matrix of zeros, B, is created with the required size and then A random locations of B are changed to 1

```
A = 5;
B = zeros(5,5);
B(randperm(numel(B),A)) = 1
```

output

```
B =

     0     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1
     1     0     1     0     1
     0     0     0     0     0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative solution using [datasample](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/datasample.html) in which , similarly to @RTL's solution, you first create a matrix of zeros and then add a given number of ones:

```
clc;
clear all;

A = 5;
B = zeros(5,5);

y = datasample(1:size(B,1)*size(B,2),A) % Randomly select 5 (i.e. A) linear indices which will be replaced by 1.

B(y) = 1
```

y =

```
12    17     1    22    14
```

B =

```
 1     0     0     0     0
 0     0     1     1     1
 0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     1     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0
```